# Publishing content in bulk vs publishing periodically

Tags: seo, publishing

For a video site (around 500 videos already published), I now have around 60 videos to be published. The next set of videos will come in 6 months.

Usually it is said that Google prefers fresh content and therefore publishing periodically is good. Yet, having more content on the site is also good.

I could not find a comparison between publishing in bulk or periodically.

So the question is: In terms of SEO is it better to publish all videos at once, or would publishing periodically for a longer duration be better?

**Edit**: In the light of the comments made, let me try to explain a few things I failed to clarify in the original question:

1. The content is related with health and is evergreen. It will not become obsolete in 2-3 months.
2. 60 videos might not seem to be a big deal when compared to 10.0000 pages but this website has a total of 500 videos. We are talking about more than 10% of the total content (At the moment it also receives relatively good traffic -around 500 visitors per day).
3. By "fresh content", I meant the website being updated regularly. My impression is that a website that has new content every week is considered better then a website that is updated once every six months, even if the total numbers of pages are the same.

Comment: Bulk is only a problem when you are talking about 100,000+ pages at once.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, rather than being a problem, I am asking about the comparison of the benefits of uploading 60 pieces of content vs uploading, say, pieces of content per week for 20 weeks.

Comment: The content isn't going to be as fresh if you wait to release it.   Fresher is better for topics that deserve freshness (news).   For evergreen topics it shouldn't matter much.

Comment: I agree with Stephen, 10,000+ requires consideration, however, 60 does not. Just let 'er rip and be done with it. Best option. You got it? Put it to work for you. It is as simple as that. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Periodically releasing new content is great if you have *subscribers*.  You will get more traffic from an email list or RSS feed if you release 60 videos one per day rather than 60 at once.

For SEO, it doesn't matter how often you put new content on your website.   In fact, Google often rewards updating and expanding existing content more than creating new pages with new content.

You just have to have fresh enough content to keep users happy.  A website that looks stale isn't going to do well with users.   News gets stale very fast.  If you have last week's headlines on your home page, users will notice.   For most topics, you can get by without updating for months or even years before users notice.  It is only when users notice that the content is stale and start bouncing back to Google when searching that Google starts de-ranking.

Comment: You are absolutely right, the site is for the users! I am surprised to find myself looking over this fact for so long. The greed for SEO blinded me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Fresh content is not mean your website should publish new content on time. Fresh content is seo myth. News are purely fresh content, when you write something about new places then it is consider fresh content. If you publish some article like "How to create seo friendly content" in your website for fist time then it does not consider as fresh content, because there are already lot's of content about that. **In short fresh content mean Google does not aware about that things, in technical words they do not have such content on their index database.**

When you upload bulk videos on your website, then Google will not index it all the videos in one crawl. Google will crawl some of your videos today, and will crawl some of other videos on next day and so on.

If you have only 60 videos then publish it right now, there is no any SEO advantages if you gonna publish 1 video daily.

Answer (score 1):

> So the question is: In terms of SEO is it better to publish all videos at once, or would publishing periodically for a longer duration be better?

Generally, the more you publish sooner, the better chance you have of getting indexed. This is especially true if each video page you publish contains a unique category and quality text along with the video rather than just the video itself.

If you publish too frequent and too soon (for example, one video per minute for 10 hours), then your site will take a bit longer to load and search engines will be confused what to index because they like to keep a cache of everything.

If you publish too infrequent (for example: like one video a year), you might not get the traffic you'd like to see because there could be a point in time where someone wanted to see your video, but couldn't because you wanted to get x number of videos done before publishing them.

So my advice, if you get a long video done, publish it right away since people want to see it. then spend some time doing another video and then publish it.